# Calculate $a$ when the lines cross

Tags: graphing-functions

My book has given me the following

> Given are the lines $k$: $y = ax + 6$ and $l$: $y= \frac{1}{2}ax +3a$. For which $a$ do the lines $k$ and $l$ cross each other on the y-axis?

I've tried resolving this one but the ax is confusing me a lot, should I be reading $y = a \times x+6$ or is it actually $ax+6$? I'm thinking that the first thing I said was true, if it was, how would we go about calculating the $x$ in this formula?

The answer to the question is: $2$ but why? Can someone maybe explain what's going on here? I can't seem to figure this one out. Links to tutorials or resources where these subjects are explained would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: This isn't graph theory

Comment: @BDN I'm sorry, under which tag would this better fit?

Comment: graphing-functions, I've suggested an edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Two curves $y = ax+6$ and $y = ax/2 + 3a$ cross when they hit same $y$ and same $x$. so you have
$$
ax+6 = y = ax/2 + 3a
$$
Since they cross on the $y$-axis, any point there has coordinates $(0,y)$, so $x=0$, which leaves you to plug that into the above equation and find both $y$ and $a$. Can you do that?